# Angular $HTTP and Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I can't get my promise inside a HTTP.get function to work. When i try to console.log the output, all i get is the promise function?

I am interested in getting the array of events that my api has provided.

```
eventApp.factory('LoadEvents', function($http, $q) {
        var LoadEvents = function() {
            this.events = [];
            this.busy = false;
            this.after = '';
        };

        LoadEvents.prototype.nextPage = function() {
            if (this.busy) return;
            this.busy = true;

             var defer = $q.defer();

             $http.get('URL inserted here').then(function(response){
                 defer.resolve(response.data);
             });

             this.events = this.events.concat(defer.promise);


            console.log(this.events);
        };
```

This should be a very basic promise, but i can't figure out why i can't recieve the array instead of the whole promise function?

Comment: Probably because your logging the promise before it is assigned to the events.

Comment: You cannot get the array because it is loaded *asynchronously*! A promise is not the value itself.

Comment: Okay i get it. But can't really see how i can inside the $http.get function set this.events to the received data from the api?

Comment: $http returns a promise. You can just use that one instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

By the event array (i.e. `this.event`) if you want to mean the promise array then it should be like this

`this.events = this.events.concat([defer.promise]);` or `this.events = this.events.push(defer.promise)` then use `$q.all(this.events).then(...)` to get all resolved.